# Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows 10 IOT using USB Webcam

Tags: windows, webcam

I just got this new Raspberry Pi 3 and I have installed Windows 10 IOT on it. I am doing this project and it is for a webcam detecting objects. So  my question is, can I use a USB webcam on my Raspberry Pi so when I execute the code on my Raspberry Pi, it will automatically detect the webcam and will bring up an image?

Answer (score 0):

You can not detect image because Windows 10 IoT does not provide a driver for the camera - it is still in development.

So by using Raspbian OS, it is possible to use the webcam but when using Windows 10 IoT it is difficult.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a "Basic webcam app" sample that seems to fit the bill: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/webcamapp

Comment: Link-only answers, while they might work for a while, are pretty useless as soon as the other end of the link changes or moves. Can you summarise their approach or otherwise provide some clues as to namespaces/critical code chunks?

Comment: Fair enough - it should probably have been only a comment.